# Unknown loop/counter in my code

Tags: javascript, counter

This code was a series of if statements, but has now been turned into a switch statement. I'm making a rudimentary Visual Novel system. First run through, it records the dialogue into the 'script.' Then it loops back to the question. For whatever reason, when I click on the option to run it a second time, it now executes the coding for case 13 twice (as I get alerted twice by my msg and it records the dialogue twice into the 'script'). And then 3 times, etc. I've removed as much superfluous coding as I can here.

Code:

```js
var textnum = 12; //gets me to case 12.

function viewScript() { //there's a button that toggles the script on and off.
  var div = document.getElementById("fullscript");
  div.style.display = div.style.display == "block" ? "none" : "block";
}

function hideChoices() { //clears the text between cases 12 & 13. 
  document.getElementById("charchoice").innerHTML = "";
  return;
}

$("#clickarea").click(function() {
  switch (textnum) {
    case 12:
      document.getElementById("charchoice").innerHTML = "What happened to bring you here?";
      
      $("#charchoice").click(function() {
        document.getElementById("script").innerHTML += "User: What happened to bring you here? <br>";
        textnum = 13;
        document.getElementById("clickarea").click();
      });
      break;
    case 13:

      hideChoices();
      textnum = 12;
      alert("returnpls");
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
.dialoguebox {
 position: absolute;
 width: 1300px;
 height: 120px;
 line-height: 32px;
 top:520px;
 left: 15px;
 font-size: 30px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 font color: "yellow";
}

button.link {
 background:none;
 border:none;
 font-size: 26px;
 
}

#charchc1 {
 color: yellow;
}

#charchc1:hover {
 color: white;
}

#scriptbtn {
 position: absolute;
 left: 10px;
 height: 40px;
 width: 60px;
}

#fullscript {
 position: absolute;
 width: 1270px;
 height: 600px;
 left: 80px;
 background-color: black;
 opacity: .96;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 display:none;
 z-index: 10000;
}

#script {
 position: absolute;
 top: 15px;
 left: 15px;
 font-size: 20px; 
}

#clickarea {
 position: absolute;
 width: 1280px;
 height: 450px;
 left: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="viewScript()" id="scriptbtn">Script</button>

<div id="clickarea"> click area </div>

<div id="fullscript">
  <div id="script"></div>
</div>

<div class="dialoguebox">
  <button id="charchoice" class="link"><div class="charchoice"> </div> </button> <br>
</div>
```

Hopefully you guys can see what I can't. This has been stumping me all day. You'll probably want to mod the code a bit before testing it. In case 13, I no longer have dialogue showing there to simplify posting here. If you click a second time, it will loop back to case 12.

---One solution (suggested by previous person here)
is to move the charchoice outside the clickarea function:

```js
var textnum = 12; //gets me to case 12.

$("#charchoice").click(function() {
        document.getElementById("script").innerHTML += "User: What happened to bring you here? <br>";
        textnum = 13;
        document.getElementById("clickarea").click();
      });

function viewScript() { //there's a button that toggles the script on and off.
  var div = document.getElementById("fullscript");
  div.style.display = div.style.display == "block" ? "none" : "block";
}

function hideChoices() { //clears the text between cases 12 & 13. 
  document.getElementById("charchoice").innerHTML = "";
  return;
}

$("#clickarea").click(function() {
  switch (textnum) {
    case 12:
      document.getElementById("charchoice").innerHTML = "What happened to bring you here?";


      break;
    case 13:

      hideChoices();
      textnum = 12;
      alert("returnpls");
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
});
```

This seems to be the root of the problem. I'm wondering if there's a way to keep it nested in case 13 for tidiness purposes. For whatever reason, while this coding is nested there, I've created some kind of recursion that won't self terminate.

Comment: Not sure if I got you right ... in case 13 you are setting `textnum = 12` ... so you loop back to case 12... *confused*

Comment: I'm intentionally looping back to case 12. Case 13 is a simulation of talking to a character, going down a branch, and looping back to the question (case 12).